# ASP.NET MVC3 WebGrid sorting with custom objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sorting, webgrid

I want to sort by column containing objects of my own type.
Witch method should I override in my custom object (i.e. CompareTo, operator <) so the WebGrid can sort them automatically,

Much like WebGrid sorts DateTime correctly.

(I am using ASP.NET MVC 3, with .NET 4)